# Can't see second Arduino port on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have connected two arduinos to `/etc/ttyUSB0` and `/etc/ttyUSB1`.

Only one is visible in Arduino IDE. Why and how to force second?

**UPDATE**

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan  6 23:32 usb-1a86_USB2.0-Serial-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1
```

I.e. it shows port, which IS NOT SHOWN in Arduino IDE (only `/dev/ttyUSB0` is shown.

**ALSO**

I can see both ports if run `arduino` with sudo. Should I run it with sudo?

Permissions are same

```
$ ls -l ttyUSB?
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan  6 23:26 ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Jan  6 23:39 ttyUSB1
```

Comment: What means are you using to verify that both of these devices exist *right now* ?  Incidentally, unlike some other operating systems, these identifiers are newly assigned each time the device is connected, and may refer to different devices at different times.  You can even get the assigned numbers to increment with a single device, if a program holds the old device file open while it is re-plugged.

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id` show?

Comment: You can also verify it with gtkterm. Click "Configuration" and "Port" and open the drop down menu "Port:". Check if they both are there. Perhaps you can try the Arduino IDE with sudo. Did you set some kind of permission to /etc/ttyUSB0? Remove all the Arduino and Java from the repositories. Unpack the newest Arduino IDE into a folder and start it from that folder. Be sure to remove the librxtx-java from the repositories (I use synaptic).

Comment: @Jot this looks blind guessing

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can communicate with them, and they answer differently

Comment: Dims, did you try to run the Arduino IDE with sudo ? Can you tell which Arduino boards are connected? Has one of them a unknown bootloader? Did you remove Arduino, Java and librxtx from the repositories ?

Comment: Terrible advice.  You should **NEVER EVER** run the Arduion IDE (or any similar software) as root.  It's not designed to be safe for such use, and you run the risk of leaving behind files which your normal user won't be able to clean up or change.  Instead, either set up proper udev rules, put yourself in the group that owns serial devices, and restart.  Or temporarily chown the device in question to yourself - but if you do that you'll have to each time you plug it in.

Comment: just because a user has permission to access a serial port, does not mean the a user has permission to access any other ports ... access has to be granted for each com port separately, or a user has to be belong to a group that has access to previously specified ports

Answer (score 1):

You have to add use your user to the dialout group, as explained in the [installation instructions for Linux](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux).

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Then log out and back in again.